# fast forward a video with keyboard

Tags: keyboard, itunes

I have tried <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, but no luck. Instead iTunes jumps to the next video podcast.

Is there a way to fast forward ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

5 secs forward:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: How did I miss that ..   In other video apps it's simply right arrow ..  But hey at least a shortcut does exist. How did you discover it?  I went to the official docs  and nothing there at all https://support.apple.com/en-ph/guide/quicktime-player/qtpa4808515d/mac

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Even though more than ten years passed since then, I guess I found it by just trying different combos. Back then the shortcuts were a bit more consistent across the MacOS apps. Also, the initial question was referring to iTunes, so that might explain why it's not present in the link you found.